# How to fetch distinct record in liferay

Tags: search, liferay, liferay-6

I tried to fetch distinct record. But didn't get success. I tried following code

> DynamicQuery
>   dynamicQry=DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Clipping.class);
>   dynamicQry.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.isNotNull("news"));
>   dynamicQry.setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.distinct(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("news")));
>   List press =
>   ClippingLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQry);

I got following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.dbservice.model.Clipping
at org.apache.jsp.html.pressClipingReport.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:924)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

What is the solution?
please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: It wont give you distinct record but will give you distinct news field as return value

Comment: How can i get distinct record?

Comment: You may have to write two DynamicQuery, one for getting ids of distinct records and other is for getting records using ids

Comment: can you give me example please?